# Cross Apply Fails When DateTime Added

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, cross-apply

In trying to achieve a `Pivot`-ed goal for a two row data table into one row, my first thought was to use a `Cross Apply`. By using the `Cross Apply` one can identify/generate each of the rows with a specific column name derived from the row's unique id. (e.g. 'Lat1' and 'Lat2 for a 'Latitude' source column).

All is fine when I use `INT` or `FLOAT` data types but when I try to use a `DateTime` all  `VALUES` become `DateTime`.

---

**Example Shipping Lat/Long/DateTime**

We have two points in a ships journey reported on two different days:

```
CREATE TABLE #Shipping
(
     [RouteID]     [INT]  NOT NULL,
     [Latitude]    FLOAT NOT NULL, 
     [Longitude]   FLOAT NOT NULL,
     [Time]        DATETIME NOT NULL

);

INSERT #Shipping(RouteID, [Latitude], [Longitude], [Time])
VALUES          (1,         18.0221,    -63.1206,  '24-Jan-2016'), 
                (2,         17.8353,    -62.99667, '25-Jan-2016');
```

---

**Successful CrossApply**
 If we use `CrossApply` against the data for the first three columns

```
  SELECT  col+cast([RouteID] as varchar(1)) new_col
         , X.value
       FROM #Shipping
  CROSS APPLY
  (
      VALUES
         (RouteID,   'Id')
      ,  (Latitude,  'Lat')
      ,  (Longitude, 'Lon')
  ) X (value, col)
```

Our results are as expected:

[image: Cross Apply success with Int and Float]

Great!

---

**Failure CrossApply With DateTime**

But once we add `DateTime` to the mix:

```
      SELECT  col+cast([RouteID] as varchar(1)) new_col
             , X.value
           FROM #Shipping
      CROSS APPLY
      (
          VALUES
             (RouteID,   'Id')
          ,  (Latitude,  'Lat')
          ,  (Longitude, 'Lon')
          , ([Time],    'Time')
      ) X (value, col)
```

All become `DateTime`s

[image: Cross Apply failure with DateTime]

How should one work around this if my end goal is to pivot all the values from the original table into one row?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the result, the *value* column must have a data type, like always. SQL Server determines the type using the rules for [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) (more precisely, the `VALUES` clause is a `UNION`, so types are matched there).

In your first example, the precedence rules give a column of type *float*. In the second example, it is *datetime*.

Solve the problem by explicitly casting each value in the `VALUES` clause explicitly to a common type, e.g. *varchar* or *sql_variant*:

```
SELECT
    new_col = X.col + CAST(S.RouteID as varchar(10)),
    X.value
FROM #Shipping AS S
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
        (CONVERT(sql_variant, S.RouteID),   'Id'),
        (CONVERT(sql_variant, S.Latitude),  'Lat'),
        (CONVERT(sql_variant, S.Longitude), 'Lon'),
        (CONVERT(sql_variant, S.[Time]), 'Time')
) AS X (value, col);
```

or:

```
SELECT
    new_col = X.col + CAST(S.RouteID as varchar(10)), 
    X.value
FROM #Shipping AS S
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
        (CONVERT(varchar(8), S.RouteID),   'Id'),
        (CONVERT(varchar(8), S.Latitude),  'Lat'),
        (CONVERT(varchar(8), S.Longitude), 'Lon'),
        (CONVERT(varchar(8), S.[Time], 112), 'Time')
) AS X (value, col);
```

Note: Not everything can be cast to [*sql_variant*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx). From that link:

[image: Restrictions]

Everything except the old deprecated [*image*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) type can be cast to *char* or *varchar*. See the conversion matrix in [Data Type Conversion (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx):

[image: Conversion matrix]